# How to get link in a webview and pass it on to the google doc viewer in android?

Tags: android, webview

Okay so here is my main activity class.
In my `WebView` there are various links (mostly PDF). Now when a user clicks a link then what I'd like to do is i would like to load the URL in a variable then pass this variable to Google doc viewer code inside the `WebView` only to show the PDF contents.

```
package com.aeonindustries.skfgi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

So how am going to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set browser for webview and override some methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here some code:

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {   
      @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          // insert here code to handle your goal
          return true;
      }
```

And somewhere in your Activity:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Hi...i updated my question and added the full main activity class. Can you please be more specific and guide me step by step.

Comment: My answer is regarding your the first question: '"'i would like to load the url in a variable ".